# How to save HTTPS post response to global variable in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, http-post

I am trying to integrate with a payment gateway in Node and I have successfully been able to post data, but I need to grab the HTTP response status code and store it in a global variable in order to use it for validation.

```
     _doRequest(postData) {
const hostName = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
const path = '/api/transact.php';

postData.security_key = this.security_key;
postData = querystring.stringify(postData);

const options = {
  hostname: hostName,
  path: path,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Content-Length': Buffer.byteLength(postData)
  }
};

// Make request to Direct Post API
const req = https.request(options, (response) => {
  console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`);
  console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`);

  response.on('data', (chunk) => {
    console.log(`BODY: ${chunk}`);
  });
  response.on('end', () => {
    console.log('No more data in response.');
  });
});

req.on('error', (e) => {
  console.error(`Problem with request: ${e.message}`);
});
```

response.statusCode is what I'm looking to hoist somehow and store in a global variable like const status = statusCode, but I cannot figure out how to accomplish this.  I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `global.status = statusCode`.
You can always access it, while node is running, however this is considered an antipattern.

Comment: would this be used in the definition of the variable?  such as `const global.status = statusCode`?

Comment: No, just without `const`. You define the new key `status` for object `global`.
So just 
`global.status = statusCode;`
And later you may for example
`console.log(global.status);`

Comment: By adding that code to the request, it doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: Here is the updated code:  
`const req = https.request(options, (response) => {
      console.log(`STATUS: ${response.statusCode}`);
      console.log(`HEADERS: ${JSON.stringify(response.headers)}`);
      global.status = statusCode;
`

Comment: I have also tried using Object.assign, which does not seem to work either.

Comment: `global.status = response.statusCode; `

Comment: Still no luck unfortunately.